# How to print only uppercase letters in Python using isupper( ) method?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am trying to write a function that uses a for loop and the isupper method to print only the uppercase letters of a string.

what i have done so far:

```
upper_chars = ""
def only_upper(s):
    for char in s:
        if s.isupper() == True:
        upper_chars += char
 print upper_chars
```

But this is not working? Anyone tell me why?
I get this error message: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'upper_chars' referenced before assignment"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Several problems in your code:

- you should define `upper_chars` variable inside the function
- in the loop you should call `isupper()` on a character, not the whole string
- your function should return something
- you should call the function
- wrong indentation in the `if` block

Here's the code with fixes:

```
def only_upper(s):
    upper_chars = ""
    for char in s:
        if char.isupper():
            upper_chars += char
    return upper_chars

print only_upper("HeLLo WorLD")
```

---

Also, you can use `filter()`:

```
def only_upper(s):
    return filter(lambda x: x.isupper(), s)

print only_upper("HeLLo WorLD")
```

Or:

```
def only_upper(s):
    return "".join(c for c in s if c.isupper())

print only_upper("HeLLo WorLD")
```

Both print:

```
HLLWLD
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it possible with a for loop and isupper() method?

Comment: alecxe's answer is great, and you should Accept it.  The for-loop variant probably best matches your level of expertise at the moment, but I would urge you file away the filter and list-comprehension variants for now, and come back to them when you're ready.

Comment: Also, while fine in a small case like this, *in general* building up strings like that is expensive: strings are immutable, so every update allocates a brand new string and throws away the previous. Better to use a list, which is mutable, and convert it to a string at the end. That would look like this: `upper_chars = []` ... `upper_chars += char` (or `upper_chars.append(char)`) ... `print "".join(only_upper("HeLLo WorLD))`. That last statement takes the return value from `only_upper`, an array, and makes it a string by joining the elements together, with the empty string in between.

Answer (score 0):

Well a way to fix part of the problem is to make sure you call the actually function, another thing is to make sure you return the modified string, Also you if statement is not written correctly, the body of the function needs to be 4 spaces across from the beginning of the function.

Example using the isupper method and for loop

```
def upperOnly(s):
    onlyCaps = ""
    for char in s:
        if char.isupper() == True:
            onlyCaps += char
    return onlyCaps 
print upperOnly("TeSt")
```